# Replace certain values in String with another

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes, getelementsbyclassname

Let's say I had an input element:

`<input class="example" id="example"></input>`

And I wanted to set the value (which inserts text in the input element):

`document.getElementsByClassName("example")[0].value += 'example';`

But if I wanted to replace "example" with, let's say, "example2", would that be possible? I've tried experimenting with common HTML DOM keywords such as replace(), to no avail. Is this even possible at all?

Comment: what do you mean by "replace example with say example2"? is it the class of the element that you want to switch?
also, for the example you've given, yous should set an id in that element, and use document.getElementById

Comment: @JoãoVítorCosta What I meant was, whenever I set the value, it inserts text into that input element (which is a textbox in this case). My question was about whether or not the already inserted text in the input element could be altered after insertion. Responding to your getElementById suggestion, yeah I should've used that. I'm pretty used to getElementsByClassName, so that's why I used it.

Comment: yes, you can set the value to be itself modified in a way, isn't that what you're already doing in the example? you're altering the element's value

Comment: @JoãoVítorCosta My question was figuring out how to replace certain strings in the value with other strings, such as the replac() method. Regardless, there's an answer below.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (_i.e._ regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.replaceAll()`:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
function go(){
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replaceAll("example", "example2");
}
```

```html
<textarea style="width:100%">example example example2 example</textarea>
<br/>
<button onclick="go()">Replace all occurences of 'example' with 'example2'</button>
```

Unfortunately, in the example above, `example2` would become `example22`. If you don't want this behavior, try the following:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
function go(){
  split = textarea.value.split(" ");
  constructed = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
    if(split[i] == "example"){
      constructed+="example2 ";
    }else{
      constructed+=split[i]+" ";
    }
  }
  constructed = constructed.substring(0, constructed.length-1);
  textarea.value = constructed;
}
```

```html
<textarea style="width:100%">example example example2 example</textarea>
<br/>
<button onclick="go()">Replace all occurences of 'example' with 'example2'</button>
```

Comment: When running the code snippet, it says that value.replaceAll is not a function.

Comment: @Syndiate Is it? It's working for me. Send screenshots if necessary.

Comment: Well I just ran the bottom snippet and the bottom snippet works, while the top one doesn't.

Comment: @Syndiate Can't reproduce.

Comment: Odd, the error seems to occur because of my browser.